# Java program that parses words from a LaTeX file

Tags: java, parsing

Everything was working just fine except when I want to delete the unwanted commands of LaTeX using regex it doesn't work for some reason I tried different variations,

Here is my code snippet

```
  input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
  output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));

  Set<String> wordsSet = new TreeSet<String>();

  String currentWord;
  String wholeText = "";
  while ((currentWord = input.readLine()) != null)
    wholeText += currentWord + "\n";

  wholeText = wholeText.replaceAll
  (" |'|\\.|:|/|`|%|-|\\d", "\n");

  //output.print(wholeText);
  String [] asda = wholeText.split("\n");
  String [] un = {"\\documentclass", "\\usepackage", "\\input", "\\begin"
            , "\\end" , "\\vspace", "\\ref", "\\includegraphics"
        , "\\label"};

  System.out.println(asda.length);

  for (String a: asda)
  {
    for (String unw: un)
  if (a.startsWith(unw))
    continue;

    if (a.contains("-"))
  continue;
if (a.contains("/"))
  continue;
if (a.matches(".*\\d.*"))
  continue;
    a = a.replaceAll("[.,?!'`()=:-<>{} <]","");

if ( a == "\n" || a.startsWith("\\") || a.length() == 1 
    || (a.length() > 0 && !Character.isLetter(a.charAt(0))))
  if (a.startsWith("\\cite"))
    a = a.replace("\\cite","");
  else if (a.startsWith("\\textbf"))
    a = a.replace("\\textbf","");
  else if (a.startsWith("\\author"))
    a = a.replace("\\author","");
  else if (a.startsWith("\\emph"))
    a = a.replace("\\emph","");
  else if (a.startsWith("\\texttt"))
    a = a.replace("\\texttt","");
  else if (a.startsWith("\\section"))
    a = a.replace("\\section","");
  else if (a.startsWith("\\url"))
    a = a.replace("\\url","");
  else
    continue;
if(a.length() < 1)
  continue;
if(a.length() > 1 && Character.isUpperCase(a.charAt(0)) 
   && Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(1)))
   a = a.toLowerCase();
    wordsSet.add(a);
  }
  //Collections.sort(wordsSet);
  Iterator i = wordsSet.iterator();

  while(i.hasNext())
    output.println(i.next());
  System.out.println(wordsSet.size());
```

First I get everything on the latex file on a single String then I perform some substitutions using `replaceAll` method in the String class, however, I tried including the LaTeX commands which I didn't want to use at all in the substitutions but it won't work for some reason, nothing seems to work. Some of them regex I tried `"\\documentclass\\[.*\\]\\{.*\\}"`, `"\\documentclass\\[+.*+\\]\\{+.*+\\}"`, `"\\docume.*\\}"` and many more failed attempts. I don't know what's not working, in theory it should've worked just fine, any help is appreciated.

Additional information:

- The output will be all the words in the latex file sorted alphabetically
- When I encounter `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` it results in `paper]article`    and `pta`. and when I encounter  `\usepackage{a4-mancs}` I get `mancs`

  - I tried deleting the commands before substituting all the non-letters characters but it didn't work for some reason

Comment: don't use == for string equality. Use "\n".equals(a), The only reason this works at all is because of String interning. You only want to use == for primitives and for reference equality (exactly same object). Use equals for everything else.